# ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (0, 2)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to apply a new column to dataframe but I got an error.

My code looks like this:

Fill dataframe from SQL query:

```py
cursor = con.cursor()
query = """select keyword, popularity 
           from keyword_metadata 
           where keyword in (%s)"""
cursor.execute(query, (str_keywords,))
result_df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(), columns = cursor.column_names)
```

Then apply new column:

```py
def f(x):
    print(x['keyword'], x['popularity'])
    return ...

result_df['search_score'] = result_df.apply(f, axis = 1)
```

But when I tried it, I got an error like:

```
ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (0, 2)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AloneTogether, it returns in actual code, just updated.

Comment: can you post the df head as a dict, so we can recreate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your result df has 2 column and when you use from apply method, 2 argument pass to function but your function give 1 argument. Chnage your f function with 2 argument

Comment: sorry but it is not related